# Can't access web service with server name - only with ip address

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

I have a web service running under IIS 6.
I changed the identity of the application pool to a specfic user (it was under local system).
Since this change I can't access the service using the server name anymore. I can access the service only by using the IP of the server.
I want to access the service using the server name and not the IP address.
What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the change of the application pool identity is related to this issue.

I suspect a missing host header or another web site claiming the name. If a web site accepts all host headers (there could only be one per IP adress in IIS) and another defines a specific host header (your server's name for example), then the second web site "wins" and will process the requests for that host header.

Also, check your DNS settings. Does nslookup SERVERNAME resolve the right IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716618/authentication-issue-with-an-intranet-website-running-under-iis6) - it seems to be the same situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, that question doesn't seem to have a good, accepted  answer...